# To use or not to use property C#

Tags: c#, oop

In this scenario, i have this first case

```
public class WebHostBuilder : IWebHostBuilder
{
    private IConfiguration _config;
    private ILoggerFactory _loggerFactory;
}
```

and the other one is

```
public class WebHostBuilder : IWebHostBuilder
{
    private IConfiguration _config {get; set;};
    private ILoggerFactory _loggerFactory {get; set;};
}
```

My question is which of the two is correct or most commonly used?

Comment: If it's private, it's usually a field (first case). Not always, but much more often.

Comment: @Tinwor if the second one is correct then why did microsoft use the first method? Here is the full code [link](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting/WebHostBuilder.cs)

Comment: Private property? Are you sure? The point of having properties is to make them available outside if a class

Comment: They're both correct.  The one to use depends on the context/logic.

Comment: My fault. I haven't seen the private access modifiers. To swwet yesterday evening

Comment: Please read [What is the difference between a Field and a Property in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/295104/what-is-the-difference-between-a-field-and-a-property-in-c)